# Avoiding the triple quote auto-completion in xCode 9

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

How to avoid the auto completion triple quote `'''` or triple double quote `"""` in xCode when pressing the character followed by space bar.

In my development style, the multiline String is used less than a simple String so I prefer hard typing the triple characters.

- keyboard: `U.S. International - PC`
- xcode version: `9.0 beta (9M136h)`
- illustration:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce an autocompletion in Xcode 9.0 beta (9M136h) as you described. Which version are you using? Also I know about multi-line string literals with `"""`, but what is `'''` for? Did I miss something?

Comment: @MartinR you're right, `'''` doesn't seem to be of any use, I included it in my question since it was being affected by the auto-completion as well. I updated my question with an illustration of the auto-completion I'm having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

For some who'd be having the same issue, you might want to check your system's `keyboard input source` and make sure that you're using a source not allowing special latin's characters. In my case I was using `U.S. International - PC` instead of `U.S.`

On `OS X` you can edit your `input sources` by navigating to

> System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources

[image]

## Explanation

I was using `U.S. International - PC` which basically gives access to special characters (such as é, è, à, ö, etc.) by pressing a quote `'`, a backtick `, double quote `"` followed by the base character (for example `'` + `a` produces `à`). With such a configuration, you can escape all these special characters by using the `escape bar`.

`xCode 9` is generating the triple quote `'''` or triple double quote `"""` if you try to escape `'` (resp. `"`).

Comment: This is a PITA for anybody who has to type in a language other than English. I submitted a Bug Report, hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I have U.S. input source but xcode still doesn't recognize """

Comment: @Evgeny what do you mean by `xcode still doesn't recognize """`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I needed to create a string with one quote. Solved it with "\""